# true as false type assertion in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, boolean

In TypeScript, why is the following code considered valid (doesn't throw a compiler error):

```js
const bool = true as false;
```

I'm wondering about both implementation-wise and as a language design decision?

Comment: That's what type assertion *means*. You [assert](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/assert) (see meaning one) that  something is a given type. This should help explain why type assertions are not to be used lightly - if your assertion is incorrect, you purposefully mislead the compiler.

Comment: Agree with @VLAZ . When you using `as` it it mean that you are responsible for this particular line of code - not TypeScript compiler

Comment: Is there then a reason why the compiler errors for something like `const num = true as number;`?

Comment: @DennisKats as the error message says, the values don't overlap. It's a sort of protection against type asserting to the wrong thing but it's not even a very good one as it can flag positive when the assertion does make sense.